# Recommendation on Mac System Performance logging tool

Tags: open-source, osx, monitoring

Does anyone know of software for macs that can monitor the system performance of the CPU, GPU, RAM usage, disk usage, etc. and can log the data?

Free or open source would be preferred but I can get away with using a trial version.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal command TOP can be executed with flags set to dump to a logfile. GUI tool I like is Bjango Software's iStat Menu (Meters) which runs in the upper taskbar.

https://bjango.com/help/istatmenus6/gettingstarted/

Though I've not tried, I'd bet you can get to the history logs they create to generate the history graphs, so that would probably work - and Bjango is in my experience always been very responsive to reasonable requests.